# Deploying to Heroku Webpack 2.0 (loaders)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, webpack-2

Been attempting to deploy to Heroku with an Angular 1.x app. From my Heroku-Build Log, it sounds like my loaders aren't working as they should. The config is working locally using Webpack-dev-server. I do have a post-build script in my package.json for heroku. Here's the error in the Heroku Build log:

```
ERROR in: ./app/scss/main.scss
Module parse failed: /tmp/build_16ed8e80b925b82a1be02ac972b408b0/[user]-quiver-539350a/app/scss/main.scss 
Unexpected character '@' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Here's my webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: `${__dirname}/app/entry.js`,
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: `${__dirname}/build`
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLPlugin({
      template: `${__dirname}/app/index.html`
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        '__API_URL__': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
        '__DEBUG__': JSON.stringify(!production)
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I can show my entry.js if need-be. Just wondering if anyone has encountered this problem? I've been diving through docs for webpack 2.0 loader-syntax and seen a few implementations but wanted to ask before tweaking a whole bunch.

Also, my console is displaying a similar error (line 3 main.scss):

```
Cannot find module "./scss/main.scss"
    at webpackMissingModule
```

Comment: Looks like im facing something similar. Did you work it out? Any tips u can pass on for ppl following your footsteps?

Comment: Hey there, yes I ended up solving the issue - I believe it was something unrelated but I honestly can't remember. If you'd like help, could you possibly describe your issue further? (I imagine it must be nearly identical to mine) I want to say it was an issue in my package.json - feel free to post yours if you can.

Comment: Ok I've resolved my own issue mostly. I was of the maybe *misunderstanding* that it's better to keep the server dumb and therefore it only receives a compiled webpack bundle and should know nothing therefore of webpack or babel and that these packages should be under DevDependancies in package.json. Seems currently Im having heroku compile its own webpack environment. So for me currently the solution was to bring babel & webpack packages all out of DevDepedancies into production Dependancies.

Comment: Awesome, yah your server file should ideally be pretty empty while utilizing the express.static() method in a Heroku environment.

Also yes with having webpack and babel as  dev-dependencies would be a huge issue. Heroku wouldn't know to install them in your build.